# ActionController::Integration Deprecation Warning using Rails 4.0 and Rspec 2.14.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing request specs for my Rails 4.0 app, using Rspec 2.14.2, and whenever I try to run these tests, they work correctly, but spit out this deprecation warning on the command line:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::Integration is deprecated and will be removed, use ActionDispatch::Integration instead.
```

As I said, the specs work perfectly, and I can't find anything online to address this deprecation warning, so my guess is that it's a problem with my spec code. My spec file is as follows

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authenticating" do

  it "should create a new authentication" do
    expect {
      visit "/auth/developer"
    }.to change { Authentication.count }.by(1)
  end

  it "should create a new user" do
    expect {
      visit "/auth/developer"
    }.to change { User.count }.by(1)
  end

  it "should create a new device" do
    expect {
      visit "/auth/developer"
    }.to change { Device.count }.by(1)

    Device.last.registration_id.should_not be_nil
  end

  describe "with an existing user and authentication" do

    before do
      @test_user.authentications.create(:provider => "developer", :uid => "my@email.com")
    end

    it "shouldn't create a new authentication" do
      expect {
        visit "/auth/developer"
      }.not_to change { Authentication.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "shouldn't create a new user" do
      expect {
        visit "/auth/developer"
      }.not_to change { Authentication.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "should create a new device" do
      expect {
        visit "/auth/developer"
      }.to change { Device.count }.by(1)

      @test_user.devices.last.registration_id.should_not be_nil
    end

  end

end
```

Of course, the deprecation warnings don't affect the actual function of my tests, but they're quite annoying when they show up every time I run `rspec spec`, and I would really love to be rid of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply change the class from `ActionController::Integration` to `ActionDispatch::Integration`, this is backwards compatible with Rails 3.

Comment: Yes, this would make sense, but I never tell rspec to use ActionController::Integration anywhere in my code, it just does it when executing this spec.

Comment: Can you confirm it solves the problem?

Comment: Uh no, as I said there's no way for me to "change the class" as you say it.

Comment: Start reading this test file from the top, in the first line (or maybe some next) you should have an inheritance like `< ActionController::Integration`, change it do the other class.

Comment: No, I don't. Because this is Rspec, my test file starts only with `require 'spec_helper'`; there is no inheritance going on. The name ActionController::Integration does not appear anywhere in my entire project.

Comment: Ok, can you paste WHOLE file? Best if you update the question with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33416/discussion-between-michael-szyndel-and-maxluzuriaga)

Comment: Is there any stack trace information? I found quite a few references to this warning in a Google search, suggesting the problem lies in one of the gems you're using.

Comment: No stack trace information, no. I did run `bundle update`, so all my gems are up to their most recent version, but this deprecation warning still persists.

Comment: I have this same issue, but with cucumber.  The line `require 'cucumber/rails'` triggers it, which means it's a Rails 4 issue and not in my code.  I'm guessing the same for @maxluzuriaga.

Comment: maxluzuriaga did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problems.

Comment: @henryeverett Unfortunately no I never managed to get rid of this warning. The code still works fine, but the warning is pretty damn annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are using [Webrat](https://github.com/brynary/webrat), and the answer is to move away from Webrat and over to [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

As of now, Webrat hasn't been updated in almost a year.

Allegedly, it's as simple as editing your [Gemfile](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs). Realistically, though, you will likely have to rewrite a substantial portion of your acceptance specs (as I am currently having to do).

If you're wedded to Webrat, the offending code within the gem appears to be [here](https://github.com/brynary/webrat/search?q=ActionController%3A%3AIntegration&ref=cmdform). You could always fix it and submit a pull request.

But moving to the more-updated Capybara gem seems like a better idea, long-term.

Comment: I had `gem 'webrat'` and wasn't even using it.  Removing it got rid of the warning.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Webrat?  If so, try replacing it in your gemfile with Capybara instead.  If you do this, be sure to add the following to spec_helper.rb, anywhere in the RSpec.configure block:

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

At least, that's what made the warnings go away for me...  Got the above line while spelunking in M. Hartl's Rails Tutorial source.

Answer (score -1):

Just open, find and replace inside these files:

`rspec.rb`
`world.rb`

find: `ActionController`
replace to: `ActionDispatch`

In my distro theses files are located at:

```
/home/>>>>>> YOUR USER NAME HERE <<<<<<</.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/
```

and

```
/home/>>>>>> YOUR USER NAME HERE <<<<<<</.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/rails/
```

or just locate the files with "locate" in terminal, like

```
$ locate rspec.rb
```

if you can't find, try before:

```
$ sudo updatedb
```